# Orbeon Forms: Convert Dynamic URL string into hyperlink

Tags: orbeon

We can generate a URL string in a Text Control using the following Calculated Value option:

```
concat('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=', $Latitude, '%2C', $Longitude)
```

And this will return something like:
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=51.5067%2C-0.07357

But how do we convert this into a hyperlink that the user can click on?

Many thanks in advance.

PeteA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a Calculated Value control to generate the HTML link. So your expression will look something like:

   ```xml
   concat(
       '<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=', 
       $Latitude, '%2C', $Longitude,
       '">Link to map</a>'
   )
   ```
2. Edit the source of the form (Advanced, Edit Source), and add the attribute `mediatype="text/html"` `<xf:output>` that corresponds to your control.

Comment: Hi Alex,

Neither of these work for me: 

<xf:output id="URLString2-control" bind="URLString2-bind" mediatype="text/html">
  <xf:label ref="$form-resources/URLString2/label"/>
  <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/URLString2/hint"/>
  <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
</xf:output>

Or:

'<xf:input id="URLString-control" bind="URLString-bind">
  <xf:label ref="$form-resources/URLString/label"/>
  <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/URLString/hint"/>
  <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>

<xf:output mediatype="text/html">
</xf:output>

</xf:input>'

Comment: Ok, I got the code above working using a Calculated Value control.
I made a slight change to the HTML code to open the URL in a new window:
concat(
    '<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=', 
    $Latitude, '%2C', $Longitude,
    '">Link to map</a>'
)

Comment: @PeteAtkin Excellent, I am glad that generating the link with the `<xf:output mediatype="text/html">` worked for you, and thanks for the update.